# How to release chrome extension from GitHub repository

Tags: javascript, github, google-chrome-extension

I have the code for my chrome extension on GitHub, which I want to publish on Chrome Store. Doing it manually once is fine, but I want to make an automated flow, where as soon as any commit comes to a `release` branch, chrome extension on the chrome store is also updated. Is there any documentation by any developer or Google which explains how to setup this for my chrome extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using GitHub Actions to automate publishing. High-level steps are:

1. Building and packing your extension into zip file.
2. Obtaining ([action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/fetch-google-api-access-token)) an access token for Google API (. using *clientId*, *clientSecret*, *refreshToken* (how get them? [Docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/webstore/using_webstore_api/), [Article](https://github.com/fregante/chrome-webstore-upload/blob/main/How%20to%20generate%20Google%20API%20keys.md)).
3. Upload zip as a new version to Web Store using API ([action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/upload-an-extension-to-chrome-web-store))
4. Once the uploaded version was reviewed, publish it ([action](https://github.com/marketplace/actions/publish-an-extension-on-chrome-web-store)).

However, there are some pitfalls in this process, such as undocumented responses from Google API, the need for repeating the uploading if it happened shortly after the previous one, refresh token expiration. If you want to build a convenient and robust workflow based on GitHub Actions to handle all these cases I can recommend reading [this series of articles](https://cardinalby.github.io/blog/post/github-actions/webext/1-introduction/).

Comment: All the action links are dead :(

Comment: @IceBotYT Thx for a hint, fixed

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to do this:

- by using [npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chrome-webstore-upload) ([article about that](https://gokatz.me/blog/automate-your-chrome-extension-deployment-in-minutes/)) (suits for you. You can setup script by using this module, then make a hook for a Travis CI)
- [by using Store APi](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api) // for additional reading
- by using [docker](https://circleci.com/blog/new-video-series-drawn-out-conversations-with-rob-zuber/) // for additional reading

Comment: I think you could also hook into usage of the NPM module from a new GitHub Actions workflow to not rely on Travis CI or similar services external to GitHub.